# Security of Microsoft key container

Tags: windows, key-management

How is the security of cryptographic keys stored by Microsoft Windows in the key containers used by CryptoAPI/CNG guaranteed?
The keys are stored in the user's directory or a directory for the machine-level keys (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/key-storage-and-retrieval?redirectedfrom=MSDN#key-directories-and-files). The key containers can be iterated by a logged-in user and every application. Is the only possibility to guard the keys from being used by another application to set the NTFS permissions on the files appropriately? Or is there any other way to limit key container access per application?